# std::transform wrapper with pointer to member functionand back_inserter

Tags: c++, c++14, std

I created a wrapper for std::transform to not pass both begin and end every time.

```
template <typename C, typename C2, typename UnaryOperation>
void transform(const C& c1, C2& result, const UnaryOperation& up)
{
    std::transform(std::begin(c1), std::end(c1), std::begin(result), up);
}
```

I can use like this

```
utils::transform(container, result, [](const auto& o) {return doSometing;});
```

I would like another signature where I could do something like

```
struct X {
    Object foo(std::string const& ) const;

    void bar(std::vector<std::string> const& container) const
    {
        std::vector<Object> result;
        utils::transform(container, std::back_inserter(result), &X::foo);
        // do something with result
    }
};
```

But this doesn't work. What am I missing here? Something the in the signature? How do I make it work?

Comment: You also need to pass `this` for the object, not just the member function pointer.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe What about `std::mem_fn` ?

Comment: You also pass the object/this there.

Comment: Even with `auto f = std::bind(std::mem_fn(&Object::func), this);` and passing `f` to the std::transform as  last parameter does not compile

Comment: In the call to `utils::transform(container, ..., &Object::myFunction)`... the `container` here contains `Object`s, that you want to call `myFunction` on, correct?

Comment: @Barry Yes. Correct.

Comment: Oh wait @Barry I read too fast here, actually I want to pass the object from the container to the parameter of the `&Object::myFunction`

Comment: @MaximeRoussin-Bélanger What do you mean to the parameter? Can you provide a [mcve]? It's unclear to me what specifically you're trying to do.

Comment: @Barry I just added the forloop I'm trying to transform with std::transform.

Comment: Still not clear to me what that means. This is in the context of some class `X`, that has a member function `Object X::memberFunc(std::string const&) const`?

Comment: @Barry Exactly that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example `&X::foo` is a function that takes *two* arguments: an explicit one (the `std::string const&`) and an implicit one (the `X`). But your `transform()` wants a *unary* callable. There's a mismatch there.

You need to "bind" the implicit object parameter to `&X::foo` so that it becomes unary. The easiest way to do that is with a lambda:

```
utils::transform(container, std::back_inserter(result),
    [this](auto const& s) { return foo(s); });
```

You could also use `std::bind()`... but... don't.

Comment: `std::bind(&Object::member_func, this, std::placeholders::_1);` Should work, but it's isn't really easy to use.

Comment: `std::begin(std::back_inserter(result))` would still be invalid.

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm using `C2&&` and replaced the `std::begin(result)` with `std::forward`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda as in your first usage example.

```
Object object;
auto lambda_for_member_myFunction = [object](const auto& o) {
   return object.myFunction(o);
};
utils::transform(container, std::back_inserter(result), lambda_for_member);
```

Now you could wrap this in another helper, but you would still need to add `object` as a parameter.